# Excel Sum another sheet with Indirect

Tags: sum

To sum data from another sheet, I use:

=SUM('SHEETNAME'!A1:A2)

However, I can't figure out how to sum data from another sheet if I use INDIRECT function with it.

I tried:

=SUM('SHEETNAME'!INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("E",C11)):INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("D",C11)))

The CONCATENATE data is on active sheet.  I just need the SUM data from another sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("SHEETNAME!E"&C11&":D"&C11))
```